# Broadcast receiver should always keep on running in background even my app is closed

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I have one use case that is:

My application having broadcast receiver. That broadcast receiver should always keep on running in background even my app gets closed or removed from the recent apps or whatever it may be - it should be running in background.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried alarm manager?

Comment: There are a number of ways to run in the background, depending on what your use case actually is. Your question is not specific about that (what is it that you're actually trying to do in the background?), so it's hard to recommend you a solution. I suggest reading [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), or editing your question to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve. Or both :)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a class extending `BroadcastReceiver`: You don't need to run it in background. Declare it on AndroidManifest. It's `onReceive()` method will always be called when System sends the specific broadcast (no matter your app is running or closed).
2. If you are talking about a `BroadcastReceiver` object: You should create a background Service. How? Extending `Service` class.

Answer (score 1):

A `BroadcastReceiver` (receiver) is an Android component which allows you to register for system or application events. All registered receivers for an event are notified by the Android runtime once this event happens.

So `BroadcastReceiver` is not for running Background tasks.

Consider an example that you have to call a web service and completion of the service you have to show a message to the user if the app is in foreground.In this case you can use [`WorkManager`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-basics-beba51e94048) to call the web service and then invoke the BroadcastManager to show the message which will we registered only when app is in forground.When the app goes to background,unregister the receiver.